# Adding tikz nodes dynamically relative to anchor

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, anchor

I am trying to reconstruct a CV that I've originally built in InDesign in LaTeX and have come to the conclusion that I must redo it since I most likely will not find a tool to convert InDesign files (or PDFs) to LaTeX properly.

To clarify, this is **what I want to achieve**:
[image]

and I thought of achieving this by adding nested tikzpicture-environments to be able to include multiple job positions. My issue, however, is that I want to be able to add these dynamically without needing to fiddle with the distance between the top layer of the gray box every time. This is what I currently have:

[image]

with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=5mm, right=5mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\definecolor{customblue}{HTML}{00b9f2}
\definecolor{customgray}{HTML}{f9f9fa}
\definecolor{customyellow}{HTML}{fede00}
\definecolor{customfontcolor}{HTML}{2c2e35}


% BoxText, BoxVerticalShift, Position, Department, Company, MonthStart, MonthEnd, JobDescription
\newcommand{\addYellowBox}[8]{%
    \node [fill=customyellow, minimum width=\textwidth-5mm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north west, text depth=1\baselineskip, text=customfontcolor, yshift = #2] (yellowbox) at (mainbox.north west) {#1};
    \node [text=black, anchor=north west, xshift=2mm, yshift=-2mm, align=left] at (yellowbox.north west) {#3};
    \node [text=black, anchor=north west, xshift=2mm, yshift=-6mm, align=left] at (yellowbox.north west) {#4, #5};
    \node [anchor=north east, xshift=-2mm, yshift=-2mm, align=right] at (yellowbox.north east) {#6 - #7};
    \node [text=black, anchor=north west, xshift=2mm, yshift=-12mm, align=left] at (yellowbox.north west) {#8};
}

\newcommand{\addFirstBox}[8]{%
    \node [fill=customyellow, minimum width=\textwidth-5mm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north west, text depth=1\baselineskip, text=customfontcolor, yshift = #2] (yellowbox) at (mainbox.north west) {#1};
    \node [text=black, anchor=north west, xshift=2mm, yshift=-2mm, align=left] at (yellowbox.north west) {#3};
    \node [text=black, anchor=north west, xshift=2mm, yshift=-6mm, align=left] at (yellowbox.north west) {#4, #5};
    \node [anchor=north east, xshift=-2mm, yshift=-2mm, align=right] at (yellowbox.north east) {Since #7};
    \node [text=black, anchor=north west, xshift=2mm, yshift=-12mm, align=left] at (yellowbox.north west) {#8};
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [fill=customblue, minimum width=5mm, minimum height=4cm, anchor=north] (bluebox) at (0,0) {};
        \node at (bluebox) [rotate=90, text=white, anchor=center] {Working Experience};
        \node [fill=customgray, minimum width=\textwidth-5mm, minimum height=2cm, anchor=north west, text depth=20\baselineskip, text=customfontcolor] (mainbox) at (bluebox.north east) {};

        \addFirstBox{Box 1}{0}{Position}{Department}{Company}{}{Jan 2002}{Job Description}
        \addYellowBox{Box 2}{-22mm}{Position}{Department}{Company}{Jan 2001}{Jan 2002}{Job Description}
        \addYellowBox{Box 3}{-44mm}{Position}{Department}{Company}{Jan 2000}{Jan 2001}{Job Description}
        \addYellowBox{Box 4}{-66mm}{Position}{Department}{Company}{Jan 2030}{Jan 2001}{Job Description}

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

1. How can I do this properly?
2. Eventually, I'll run into problems with the gray background where I will need to extend it manually. Is it a better aproach to get rid of the gray background and just set the yellow background color to gray?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Completely different approach: have you considered tcolorboxes instead of manually creating your box? The blue thingy at the left hand side could be the title of the tcolorbox and inside would be normal text. This will allow much easier line spacing than manually shifting the lines around.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz No, I haven't because I didn't know them. Good point, I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Can you replace the `...` in your code with the stuff needed to actually compile it?

Comment: @cfr Yes, done.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at `background` for the grey box? But if you want the whole page grey, you could just use `\pagecolor{}` from `xcolor`. I'd agree with the `tcolorbox` suggestion. There are some similar packages, too, but attaching the title at the side probably makes `tcolorbox` a good option. If it were just the grey/yellow boxes, it would be overkill.

Comment: @cfr The whole page should remain white with grey boxes on top. The yellow boxes are just yellow to see them more clearly. I'll look into background and tcolorbox, thanks! Any opinion(s) on how to define the anchors dynamically?

Comment: With your current approach (which I don't recommend), I would use the `backgrounds` library. Then you can create the grey box at the end using `on background layer` to put it behind the other boxes, when their sizes are known. You can also place nodes relative to other nodes. Use the `positioning` library for that.

Comment: @fieseler You shouldn't nest `tikzpicture` environments. Unless you really, really know exactly what you're doing. Stuff will break. So, insofar as you question is how to do that, the answer is, 'don't'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comments, I would suggest using the tcolorbox package instead of tikz. This way you don't have to worry about positioning things:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=5mm, right=5mm, top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\definecolor{customblue}{HTML}{00b9f2}
\definecolor{customgray}{HTML}{f9f9fa}
\definecolor{customyellow}{HTML}{fede00}
\definecolor{customfontcolor}{HTML}{2c2e35}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{foobox}[1]{
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  size=minimal,
  frame empty,
  colbacktitle=customblue,
  colback=lightgray,
  attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight,xshift=-\tcboxedtitlewidth},
  boxed title style={frame empty, interior hidden,sharp corners,rotate=90},
  underlay boxed title={\fill[customblue] (interior.north west) rectangle ++(-\tcboxedtitlewidth,-\tcboxedtitleheight);},
  enlarge left by=\tcboxedtitlewidth,
  width=\linewidth-\tcboxedtitlewidth,
  height=\tcboxedtitleheight,
  height plus=\textheight,
  title=#1
}

\newtcolorbox{yellowbox}{
  sharp corners,
  enhanced,
  frame empty,
  colback=yellow,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{foobox}{Working Experience}
\begin{yellowbox}
Position \hfill Date

Department

Description
\end{yellowbox}

\begin{yellowbox}
Position \hfill Date

Department

Description
\end{yellowbox}

\begin{yellowbox}
Position \hfill Date

Department

Description
\end{yellowbox}
\end{foobox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks so much cleaner, thank you very much!

Comment: @fieseler You're welcome!

Comment: Quick question though: I'm currently going throug the tcolorbox manual but I couldn't (yet) find what I'm looking for. Suppose I want to leave the blue box empty, have the same width as the other ones but set its height to the content in the grey box. Is there a way to do that? If not, how can I set the height of the *blue box* individually without having it relative to the title attribute?

Comment: @fieseler If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Comment: I think the manual could use an example like this. I could not figure out where to put the `rotate` ....

Comment: @cfr I just edit the code to be a bit less hacky. If you think this would be a useful example, please feel free to suggest it to the author.